# How to hide edges and show object mesh?

Tags: modeling

Good afternoon, please help, tell me how to make a cube like this:

[image]

and I'm not talking about edit mode, this cube looks like this in any mode

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a simple cube, subdivided in _Edit Mode_ (either subdivided twice with the default 1 cut or subdivided once set to 3 cuts), rotated and viewed in _Wireframe_ mode.

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann Good afternoon, I need the object to be a grid. This is not Wireframe mode. I know how to subdivide the cube and rotate it, but I don't understand how to make the edges transparent and enable the grid display in any mode. Do you want me to attach a file, take a look? Or is my explanation enough for you?

Comment: Ah okay, it has no faces. Go to _Edit Mode_, select all with _A_, then hit _X_ and choose _Delete_ > _Only Faces_. Would have been easier if you said in which mode we are looking at it (although your new screenshot shows _Wireframe_ mode now, which would fit my first explanation).

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann Yes, that's what I need, thanks. How did I not think of this before. For some reason I thought there was some kind of tool.

Comment: Well, when watching in _Wireframe_ mode you wouldn't even have to delete the faces ;)

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann Wait, there's a problem. When using the boolean modifier, I don't get what I want... =( I added a screenshot in the post, the last one.

Comment: It's just that it's easier and more informative to work with a boolean modifier

Comment: You didn't say anything about a _Boolean Modifier_ before ;) The _Boolean Modifier_ doesn't work with open meshes or at least not very well, and since this is a faceless mesh it is of course open. If you want complex edge-only geometry, it would be best to first create the mesh you want with the modifier, then apply the modifier and delete the faces afterwards. Or just use a _Wireframe_ modifier instead of deleting faces.

Comment: Maybe it would be sufficient if you simply go to the _Object Properties_ and under _Viewport Display_ choose _Display As_ > _Wire_?

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann Yes, thanks, this is what I need, just this cube has such a property enabled. You can answer, I will vote for the best =)

Comment: Well, now that we finally figured that out... I guess, "tell me how to make a cube like this" was a bit vague to find a solution to what you actually wanted.

Comment: If you want a solid, manifold mesh, suitable for booleans: start with your subdivided cube.  Do not delete faces.  Give it a wireframe modifier with "boundary" checked.  Adjust radius for the wireframe modifier to taste.